# frequency divider in Verilog with JK Flip-Flop

Tags: verilog, cpu-architecture

this my JK_FF code :

```
module JK_FF(j,k,clk,Q);

input j,k,clk;
output reg Q;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if (j==0 && k==0)
        Q=Q;
    else if (j==0 && k==1)
        Q=0;
    else if (j==1 && k==0)
        Q=1;
    else
        Q=~Q;   
end
endmodule
```

And this is my frequency divider

```
module freqDivider(clk,Q);
input clk;
output reg Q;
reg j2;

JK_FF f1(.j(~Q),.k(0),.clk(clk),.Q(j2));
JK_FF f2(.j(j2),.k(0),.clk(clk),.Q(Q));


endmodule
```

this is the circuit:

[image]

Output is not correct , it's always 1:

[image]

what's wrong with my code ?

EDIT AFTER ANSWERS (SOLVED):

So silly mistake , confusing VCC with JND !! i change .k(0) to .k(1), and result :
[image]

Comment: What does your testbench look like? How is internal signal `j2` behaving? Why are the `k` connections different between your module and your schematic?

Comment: @JoeHass O !!! :-O !! Your right , i confused VCC with JND :-O !! what can i do now ? should i remove my question ??!! so silly question!! :(( :'( thanks by the way Joe ;) if i change .k(0) to .k(1) is it all like schematic ?

Comment: @DEopen, k should be connected as `.k(1'b1)`. `.k(1)` will give the correct result but should give an width miss match warning as it infers `.k(32'd1)` (a 32bit input connecting to a 1bit port). It is recommended to use explicit widths and radix everywhere in your design.

Comment: you should use nonblocking statements in always blocks used to model flip flops. http://www.asic-world.com/tidbits/blocking.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a JK-FlipFlop, and `k` tied to 0 you can only ever set the output or maintain state.

A JK state table is:

```
J  K | Q
--------
0  0 | Q  (Maintain)
0  1 | 0  (Reset)
1  0 | 1  (Set)
1  1 | ~Q (Toggle)
```

Tying k to 0 you now have:

```
J  K | Q
--------
0  0 | Q  (Maintain)
1  0 | 1  (Set)
```

Which is why once your output reaches 1 it stays there.

A digital frequency divider can easily be done with standard D-Types though. Actually a good little [animation on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_divider#Digital_dividers). Or another site [here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/counter/count_1.html).

Basically each flop connects D to Q_BAR. and Q_BAR becomes the clock to the next stage.

Comment: Thanks @Morgan, in fact my teacher ask me to write verilog description for that schematic, i change .k(0) to .k(1) , and it's work now, so silly mistake, confusing VCC with JND !!!